# How can i make the width of a div till the right end of the page, if theres a margin-left in css

Tags: html, css

I am making a page with two main divs. One of them shows the content of the page, and the other one is a options menu.
The options menu is a fixed div on the left side of the page. It has a fixed width of 180px. The content div has a margin-left, which is 200px (Because the options div has a padding of 10px). In the content div there's a very long table, which is too long for the page. The content div should scale completely to the end of the page, but i don't know how.

I hope you understand what I mean and I would be glad if someone can help!

`Edit:` The Content div should have an "overflow: scroll;" then.

```css
.options{
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content{
  margin-left: 200px;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 
 td{
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <h1>Options</h1>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <table border>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Example Text 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 8
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 9
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 10
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 11
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 12
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 13
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 14
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 15
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 16
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 17
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 18
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 19
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 20
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 21
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 22
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 23
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 24
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 25
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 26
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 27
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 28
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if you want to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) but it could be usefull for you If you don't want to use bootstrap you can look *display : flex* in css [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc()` to calculate the width of content div, in this case it's `calc(100% - 200px)` and then add `overflow: auto` to it.

Demo:

```css
.options{
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content{
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  overflow: auto;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 
 td{
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <h1>Options</h1>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <table border>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Example Text 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 8
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 9
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 10
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 11
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 12
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 13
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 14
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 15
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 16
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 17
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 18
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 19
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 20
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 21
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 22
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 23
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 24
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 25
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 26
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 27
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 28
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is, that the body overflow is still there

Comment: But now the content div can scroll. Can you describe more detail?

Comment: So, i addet the overflow auto, but it didn't change anything, because the body overflow was still there. So i made the body overflow hidden. Then the content overflow was still not shown, so i made the content overflow scroll. Then it showed up but the scrollbar didn't. And the table was above the scroll line. if you understand what i mean

Comment: can you provide link to your page so that i can inspect more?

Comment: Wait a few minutes, i'm uploading it to my server! But i have to change a few things, because it uses a few php mysql scripts to show the table!

Comment: Here's the link: [Table](http://kevwpl.ga/StackOverFlow/tabledata.html)

Comment: because your table has `position: absolute`, just remove it and then you can scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `width clac` to content section.

```css
.options{
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content{
      width: calc(100% - 200px);
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 
 td{
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <h1>Options</h1>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <table border>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Example Text 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 8
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 9
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 10
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 11
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 12
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 13
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 14
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 15
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 16
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 17
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 18
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 19
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 20
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 21
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 22
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 23
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 24
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 25
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 26
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 27
      </td>
      <td>
        Example Text 28
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```